# How to populate data to mysql in spring boot on runtime?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot microservice. For environments other than prod, I have created a component
that doing something like that:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="data.populate.required", havingValue="true")
public class DataService implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;
    
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        init();     
    }   
    
    private void init() {
        List<MyEntity> list = new ArrayList<>(5000);
        for (int i=0; i<5000; i++) {                        
            list.add(new MyEntity(null, "Name" + i);    //id, name                      
        }   
        myRepository.saveAll(list); 
    }
}
```

In prod properties file the data.populate.required is set to false so we are good here.
When running mvn install from eclipse, the component running the code and insert the records
into the database.
The process is working fine after checking the database tables include the count.

But it looks like I missing something here. I'm expecting this code to run on Application Ready,
I didn't even started the application.
Is this normal behavoiur that this all done by the build process? To me it doesn't make sense cause I can't even do small thing like count the time the process takes.

UPDATE
I do have test classes with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:mytesting.properties")
public class MyServiceTests {
```

I've tried to put the property in the mytesting.properties file:

```
data.populate.required=false
```

the data is still populated.

the only way I was able to skip the data inserted is by configure the property in the main application.properties file.

```
data.populate.required=false
```

Which means it won't run on startup either.

Comment: Do you have any integration tests?

Comment: Yes, I do have.

Comment: TestPropertySource annotation has very specific logic to find resource defined as locations attribute. Check Javadoc for details. You can also define you property directly there as attribute, I guess.

Comment: I've updated the question since your first comment, the propery is not used in test properties file.

Answer (score 0):

the comments from Mar-Z directed me to two things:

1. Integration tests.
2. @TestPropertySource doesn't work properly.

After long hours today I found the solution which is adding the following
annotation to ALL tests classes:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
```

I must say that the mytesting.properties include other propery which is working without this change.

After adding the following, the data.populate.required=false in mytesting.properties
is populated correctly, the same propery is true in the main application.properties
files which bring me to the right outcome:

- Run mvn install - the component didn't run - no data population.
- run as spring boot application - data populated.

If in the future, a developer will create a new test class and won't use this annotation, it all break which means that it leave me with some worry but you need
to know what you are doing.

Hope it help others who facing similar issue.